# Drawing $\lvert z-2\rvert + \lvert z+2\rvert=5$ in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If we substitute $z=x+iy$ to $\lvert z-2\rvert + \lvert z+2\rvert=5$ and solve for $iy$ we will get

$$ iy=-\frac{1}{2}(2x-5) $$
$$ iy=-\frac{1}{2}(2x+5) $$

Then we can draw like in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane. This way we get two parallel lines.

Do you think this approach is correct for the complex plane? Just want to make sure.

Comment: You seem to have ignored the modulus signs... what you get by substituting $z=x+iy$ is $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}=5$.

Comment: `solve for iy` The next two equations are wrong and don't follow from the given relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1)$ If you want go through a geometric approach: by definition of ellipse one can conclude that $z$ is on an ellipse with foci $-2$ and $2$ and bigger axis equal to $5$.

$2)$ If you want go through an analytic approach you can write $z=x+iy$ and then

$$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}=5$$

$$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}=5-\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}$$

Square both sides:

$$(x-2)^2+y^2=25-10\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}+(x+2)^2+y^2$$

$$10\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}=25+8x \rightarrow 100[(x+2)^2+y^2]=(25+8x)^2$$

Can you finish?

Comment: How do we draw the ellipse exactly form a bunch of square roots? We can square LHS and RHS, but we'll still get one square root. How do we deal with it for precise drawing?

Comment: take a look again. Is that clear? You should be able to finish.

Answer (score 6):

This is an ellipse with foci at $2$ and $-2$.

Comment: So it is centered at the origin and symmetrical with the axes. Put $x=0$ and $y=0$ in the eq. in*@kccu*'s comment to find the semi-axes.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the set of points, for which the sum of distances from points $p_0=2$ and $p_1=-2$ is equal to $5$.

Sounds like an ellipse.

Comment: But if -2 and 2 are two foci of the ellipse then it doesn't looks like the distance from -2 to 2 which equals 5.

Comment: @sequence - foci don't have to belong to an ellipse. I've changed my answer a little to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

the equation is given by $$\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x+2)^2+y^2}=5$$
square it!

Comment: Actually I did, but got a massive square root "in the middle".

Comment: no, you must square two times

Comment: Right, but then we get $2$ times two square roots "in the middle" on LHS.

Comment: Unenlightening answer, as the comments show.